# Varying RAM utilization in Windows 10 Pro vm running on Hyper-V

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I have a desktop x2 Xeon e2620v3 with 32G RAM with WIN 10 Pro and Hyper-V Manager Version: 10.0.10586.0. I have a VM with Win 10 Pro installed and gave it 12G RAM.

The problem is that inside the VM in the settings tab of the windows, it says that from the 12G associated only 4,58 are usable. Sometimes it says 11,4G are usable. It varies..

Why is that? Is there anything that I can do about it? Is it because of the Dynamic Memory option in Hyper-V?

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess you have, [Dynamic memory](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817651(v=ws.10).aspx) enabled for the VM, perhaps you can verify if that is the case or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ramhound suggested the option for "Dynamic Memory" was enabled.